# Moving sprites with gameTime, why do I need to use +=?

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to move a 2D test sprite with the variable gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;

The code to update the sprites position that works is this:

```
spritePosition.X += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
```

With the above line the sprite moves to the right on runtime as expected.

However I don't understand why I need the "+=". I.e. why doesn't the following work:

```
spritePosition.X = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
```

(I understand that x += 1 is short hand for x = x + 1)

I'm passing gameTime to the update function, shouldn't it be constantly changing (and therefore constantly moving the sprite)? I feel like I'm missing something straight forward!

EDIT: The sprite doesn't accelerate. (I can test this by using Seconds rather than Milliseconds, and its clearly only moving at 1 pixel a second, and not accelerating)

Info:

Language: C#
I'm using XNA windows game template
The above single line is called in the update function

Comment: is your sprite accelerating or not?

Comment: No not accelerating. I'll add this to the above post as that's what I find odd.

Comment: With sP.X = elapsedTime, the expected behavior would be the sprite moving at a constant velocity in the x direction. With sP.X += elapsedTime, the expected behavior would be the sprite moving at an increasing velocity.  Is elapsedTime increasing per-iteration, or is it the time interval between a game-step?

Comment: I have to admit I don't know the in's and out's of elapsed time, but as I understood it its a global variable that increases with time and not iteration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `gameTime.ElapsedGameTime` is the time elapsed since the last "frame".  This means it will always about around 1/60 of a second if you're running at 60fps.

You're setting the position to a constant value.

See the description at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gametime.elapsedgametime.aspx

Comment: Bingo. Thanks. 15char

Answer (score 2):

`gameTime.ElapsedGameTime` is time since last update. So you need to add this delta therefore +=. You would use = for absolute time (`gameTime.TotalGameTime`).

You need `ElapsedGameTime` because you don't know how often update is called. So if you want constant speed let's say 1000px/s and you get only 1 update call per second (slow cpu for example) `ElapsedGameTime` will be 1000ms each time and you will move sprite BY 1000px every second.

If you get 50fps (so 50 update calls per second) `ElapsedGameTime` will be always 20ms and you move sprite by 50 * 20ms = 1000px every second.

This way you don't need to care about lags or speed of cpu.

In your example it doesn't matter. Since you do just linear move you could use `Position.X = TotalGameTime` and it would do the same thing. But when you need to determine how far sprite moved based on it's own speed since last update you will need `Position += ElapsedGameTime * (object/sprite speed)`

Comment: Bingo. Thanks. Answer to Metafight only because he got there first.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `+=` adds to the current value of `spritePosition.X` whereas `=` just assigns a new value.

If `spritePosition.X` has a value of `5` and `gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds` has a value of 10 (for the sake of this argument), then the first line of code evaluates to:

```
spritePosition.X += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;

spritePosition.X = spritePosition.X + (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;

spritePosition.X = 5 + (float)10;  // 15
```

Whereas the second evaluates to:

```
spritePosition.X = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;

spritePosition.X = (float)10;      // 10
```

Comment: I understand that I think. The point is that why do I need to add the value? As gameTime increases, as far as I can see the spritePosition should increase as well.

Comment: Okay. (see above edit). But basically the sprite doesn't accelerate (like I think it should). And when I use just "=" (and not "+=") it stays stationary, which I also don't understand.

Comment: See my answer (which I posted seconds before tskala ;) )